# Typescript recursive interface with functions

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to define a recursive interface for an object which fields are resolver functions or functions that return such objects. Here's simplified example ([playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgJWGwFcoBnBAN2AFkJsBrQsiAG2qjgG8AoOOANpJMAW2AAuOGRhRkAcwC6kgBTKykgIwBKOAF4AfHExIAnjoA+cVToMEipCtTqNmbDloDcPAL48e2CCRpODBZEQQYKlp6BnU7EnIo5yZgFnY0PW4+OAB3aFjJMj1DDQAaOAB6CrgIBkwTcqLkdDQoYAATIyKNbIAjKFrgJBUbQ2Vefn4QQuK4DUrq1ugAQilEJBaoNs7MIuMTbO8tHy8gA), thanks to @jcalz)

```
export interface RecursiveMockResolver {
  [name: string]: ((s: 1) => any) | (() => RecursiveMockResolver);
}

const primitiveMocks: RecursiveMockResolver = {
  works: s => 1, // okay, s inferred as 1
  broken: () => ({
    x: s => 1 // error! s inferred as any
  })
};
```

The problem is that typescript won't recognize argument types of `x` function (`Parameter 's' implicitly has an 'any' type.`) and I have to manually specify them for every nested resolver. `works` resolver is fine. My understanding is that it happens because typescript thinks that  `broken` is a resolver function and not a factory function.

Is it possible to define `RecursiveMockResolver` in a different way so typescript will correctly infer `x` argument types?

Comment: Does this code constitute a [mcve]?  If I drop this into [The Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/), I get an error that `MockedResolversContext` is not defined.  If it's important, please define it... or if it's not, please remove it from the example code.  Good luck!

Comment: I don't have a solution for you, but [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgJWGwFcoBnBAN2AFkJsBrQsiAG2qjgG8AoOOANpJMAW2AAuOGRhRkAcwC6kgBTKykgIwBKOAF4AfHExIAnjoA+cVToMEipCtTqNmbDloDcPAL48e2CCRpODBZEQQYKlp6BnU7EnIo5yZgFnY0PW4+OAB3aFjJMj1DDQAaOAB6CrgIBkwTcqLkdDQoYAATIyKNbIAjKFrgJBUbQ2Vefn4QQuK4DUrq1ugAQilEJBaoNs7MIuMTbO8tHy8gA) is the kind of thing I'd expect as a [mcve].  Maybe someone will have some luck proceeding from there.

Comment: Or even simpler (not recursive), [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgOWAGdUATAVSQQiQBUALZAczgG8AoOOAbSUwFtgALjgkozALpDOXOAB84ACkVERARgCUcALwA+OJiQBPDTK4LlWvWzggRKkQCYr+w0YDccAL4b37L+zYNCRwYOL8CDAIAG7AALIQ2ADWqgTEZJTUdIxILNpsMgDu0CkiRDr6AAwANHAA9HVwEEmYRrXlyOhoUMCkBuVqMgBGUM3ASPYuShyytmUVcJX1jd3QAISiiEhdUD19mOVuMj7+fkA)

Comment: My guess is that this is just too much for the compiler... keywords "contextual typing", "nested", "function": See [microsoft/TypeScript#22715](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22715) and [microsoft/TypeScript#23429](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23429)